# How can I integrate my selenium web driver code into Jenkins so that it can run periodically

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, jenkins-cli

How can I integrate my selenium web driver code into Jenkins so that it can run periodically . I have Perforce as version control.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a batch file which would contain all command required to execute your tests and you can then attach this batch file to the jenkins job which would make it run periodically or after new build is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a job in Jenkins and choose 'Execute shell' or 'Execute Windows batch command'.

Here you write the commands you usually write to fetch the repository updates and run your tests. Then run the job and set it to run at certain intervals.
Example (when using git):

```
cd /path/to/repository/directory
git pull
mvn -Dtest=Test* test
```

This will pull the updates and use Maven to run all tests in the project.